# Switch virtual desktop using mouse dragging

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop, productivity

I want to **switch my windows 10 virtual desktops by dragging with my mouse** on the edge, similiar to what you **see here**: https://youtu.be/w9-xDAnfYlI?t=95 (note: the desktop switch there has nothing to do with windows 10 virtual desktops, so this example is limited to show the dragging gesture i mean).

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you have a touchpad?

Comment: @harrymc No, I'm using a Logitech mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have a solution. I use [strokeit](https://www.tcbmi.com/strokeit/) which recognized a mouse gesture (even better) and can generate key strokes (ctrl+win+left/right for virtual desktop switching).

Nice!

Comment: Thank you. (For future visitors: Notice that its mouse gestures have to be done using the "right click button" of the mouse, and not with the left one.)

Answer (score 0):

This is also an option, but it wouldn't be dragging, it would be clicking on shortcuts

[Creating Windows Explorer shortcuts that switch desktops, and adding them to the Taskbar](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/159382-create-one-click-toolbar-switch-virtual-desktops-windows-10-a.html)

The instructions seem a bit long, but they also include some customization. In summary to get it working is pretty simple:

1. Download the executable for
   [DesktopSwitcher](https://github.com/isobit/win10-desktop-switcher) (or VDesk like they mention in the article)
2. Create shortcuts to the executable, passing the desktop index number as a parameter for each shortcut. Place them all into a folder
3. Create a Taskbar Toolbar using the shortcuts folder (right click the Taskbar > select Toolbars > New Toolbar > select the folder)